# React slick carousel getting current slide data/id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently struggling to get data from react slick carousel slides. Image is a link to another page but id of the product is always the same, the id of the last item in the array. Products are displayed properly with correct data but clicking the link doesn't get the data needed. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
const SlickCarousel = () => {
 const settings = {
   className: 'slider variable-width',
   fade: true,
   dots: true,
   infinite: true,
   centerMode: true,
   speed: 800,
   autoplay: true,
   autoplaySpeed: 6000,
   pauseOnHover: true,
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
  };
  const featured = products.slice(0, 3);
return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div className='head-line'>
        <h1>Featured products</h1>
      </div>
      <Slider {...settings}>
        {featured.map((item) => {
          const { img, id, name } = item;
          return (
            <article key={id}>
              <Link to={`/products/${id}`}>
                <img src={img} alt={name} />
              </Link>
              <h2>{name}</h2>
            </article>
          );
        })}
      </Slider>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

Comment: From the code snippet you have provided I can't see any logic that would cause the ID to be always the same for every item. The issue is probably in another component. Check out how you handle the ID in the product detail page and fix it if the issue is there. Please add the product detail code to your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.